# MVC5 Change image src in jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an image with a hard-coded src in my html file, which I need to change when a button is clicked. The relative path I am using is ~/Content/Images/img.png, which displays fine. However, when a button is clicked, I have some jquery code intended to change that image, like such.

```
$("#response-img-" + (i + 1)).attr('src', img2.png);
```

This shows the default placeholder image, not my image. Any ideas how I can get this image to change?

Comment: missing quotation in attr('src', "img2.png");

Comment: hmm, that didn't seem to do it. I tried both hard-coding that and setting it in a variable

Comment: can u post the html code?

Comment: <img id="response-img-1.png" src="~/Content/Images/img1" alt="img goes here">

Comment: var index = (i+1);
$("#response-img-" + index).attr('src', "img2.png");

try this.

Comment: I did try that as well. It looks like it is referencing the correct image, and the image does change, it just changes to the alt text and not the desired image. I'm wondering if it has to do with the relative path? The path would actually be "~/Content/Images/img2.png"

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would make it simple by storing the image url on the page in a hidden field or using a data-* attribute on the image itself. Then use JQuery to replace it.

```
<input type="hidden" value="~/Content/images/ios-startup-image-landscape.png" name="dynamicImageUrl" />
<img id="replaceMe" src="~/Content/images/ios-startup-image-portrait.png" />

 var imgUrl = $('input[name=dynamicImageUrl]').val();
 $("#replaceMe").attr('src', imgUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
<input type="button" id="yourbutton" value="ClickMe"  onclick="buttonfunction(this)"/>


function buttonfunction(obj) {
    $("#response-img-").attr('src', obj);
}
```